# using Laravel 7 Api routes

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use simple laravel api for getting and sending requests, after define this api routes in `api.php`:

```
Route::prefix('Api/v1')->group(function () {
    Route::any('login', 'Api\v1\AuthController@login');
    Route::any('register', 'Api\v1\AuthController@register');
});
```

and creating AuthController in `app/http/controller/Api/v1` directory:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        dd(request()->all());
    }

    public function register()
    {
        dd(request()->all());
    }
}
```

i get `404` error on this link:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/Api/v1/login
```

how can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Routes in `api.php` are automatically prefixed with `/api`. Currently, your routes are:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Api/v1/login
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Api/v1/register
```

So navigating to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/Api/v1/login` is a 404.

If you remove `/Api`, and just use `Route::prefix('/v1') ...` then you should have no issue.

Also, always double check your routes with `php artisan route:list` to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The API Routes are already prefixed by /api . I think the correct structure you'd looking for would be

```
Route::prefix('v1')->group(function () {
    Route::any('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::any('register', 'AuthController@register');
});
```

This way, you're calling the methods Login and Register from you /Controllers/AuthController file with the route

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/login

Answer (score 0):

You can use many ways to define routes for API in laraval > routes > api.php file.

In this i'm going to explain how we can use routes group in the laraval..

```
Route::group([
    'namespace' => 'Customers', //namespace App\Http\Controllers\Customers;
    'middleware' => 'auth:api', // this is for check user is logged in or authenticated user
    'prefix' => 'customers' // you can use custom prefix for your rote {{host}}/api/customers/

], function ($router) {
    // add and delete customer groups
    Route::get('/', [CustomerController::class, 'index']); // {{host}}/api/customers/  this is called to index method in CustomerController.php
    Route::post('/create', [CustomerController::class, 'create']); // {{host}}/api/customers/create this is called to create method in CustomerController.php
    Route::post('/show/{id}', [CustomerController::class, 'show']); // {{host}}/api/customers/show/10 this is called to show method in CustomerController.php parsing id to get single data
    Route::post('/delete/{id}', [CustomerController::class, 'delete']); // {{host}}/api/customers/delete/10 this is called to delete method in CustomerController.php for delete single data
});
```

You can create controller using artisan command with default methods

```
php artisan make:controller Customers/CustomerController --resource
```